# Sorting results based on different criteria in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a Mysql tables quote, users and followers.

```
Quote(id,user_id,quote)
Users (id,username)
followers (follower,following_id)
```

What I want to do, is to fetch all quotes, the question is about how to sort the quotes, in a way that **quotes by users I'm following are the first**, then the ones **by users who are following me**, then **quotes by other users**.

This is my sql query:

```
$sql='Select
    id,
    quote
FROM 
   quote
WHERE
    quote like '.$pdo->quote('%'.$item.'%');
```

I mean, if you're using facebook, and you started a research for your friends, you'll see that people whom you're friends with are the first to display, then the ones you may know, then the ones you may have spoken with..etc.

I find a trouble building the query after ORDER BY. Also I looked for this in the web, But I didn't find it, I think I'm not using right keywords for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Example data would help understanding your problem.

Comment: @SmootQ . . . Please show the query that you have, without the `order by`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

relationship between your tables is unclear. But you may try something like this

```
SELECT Quote
  FROM Quote q, Users u, Followers f
  WHERE q.user_id = u.id
  AND q.user_id = f.follower
UNION
SELECT Quote
  FROM Quote q, Users u, Followers f
  WHERE q.user_id = u.id
  AND q.user_id <> f.follower
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you've given me a spark for the solution, so in this case I have to use Union and not order by ...thanx +1 , I'm going to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done by querying quotes of users you are following then quotes of your followers and then others and join the results like this.

```
SELECT A.QUOTE FROM QUOTE  A WHERE A.USER_ID IN ( SELECT B.ID FROM USER B WHERE B.USERNAME IN ( SELECT FOLLOWER FROM FOLLOWERS WHERE FOLLOWING_ID=<YOUR ID> ) )
UNION
SELECT A.QUOTE FROM QUOTE A WHERE A.ID IN 
(SELECT B.ID FROM USERS B , FOLLOWERS WHERE FOLLOWING_ID=B.ID AND B.ID=<YOUR ID>)
UNION
SELECT A.QUOTE FROM QUOTE A WHERE A.ID NOT IN
( ( SELECT B.ID FROM USERS B , FOLLOWERS WHERE FOLLOWING_ID=B.ID AND B.ID=<YOUR ID>) UNION
 (SELECT B.ID FROM USER B , FOLLOWERS WHERE FOLLOWER=B.USERNAME AND B.USERNAME=<YOUR USERNAME))
```

Thanks
Niraj Rathi

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm trying UNION instead of ORDER BY. +1